# Showing that a set is normal in the space of analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

[image]

This is an exercise from Conway that I am stuck at. Here $H(D)$ is the set of analytic functions on $D$. I think I have to use the Montel's Theorem which states that being normal is equivalent to being locally bounded. But I cannot find a way to use the fact.. Could anyone please show me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The more challenging direction is $\implies.$ Suppose $\mathcal F$ is normal. For $n=0,1,\dots,$ define

$$\tag 1 M_n = \sup_{f\in \mathcal F} \left | \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} \right |.$$

Let $r\in (0,1).$ Use Cauchy's estimates and the uniform bound on $|f|$ we have on $D(0,r)$ (by Montel) to get a bound on $M_n$ that depends on $r$ and $n,$ but not on $f.$